# TextBoxes using parent control BindingContexts don't display data value

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am having a problem when I try to bind to text boxes to separate BindingContexts (via a container control such as a GroupBox).  The textboxes don't display the bound value.  (This example is based on the bindingcontext documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingcontext.bindingcontext%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

Here is the code:

```vb
Dim ds As New DataSet1

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    BindControls()
    GetData()
End Sub

Private Sub BindControls()
    Dim bcG1 As New BindingContext()
    Dim bcG2 As New BindingContext()

    GroupBox1.BindingContext = bcG1
    'GroupBox2.BindingContext = bcG2

    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Orders.OrderKey")    ' groupbox1
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Orders.OrderKey")    ' groupbox2
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Orders.OrderKey")    ' form
End Sub
```

When I run the form Textbox3 (at the form level) and textbox2 (in GroupBox2) are synchronized as expected and TextBox2 displays the value of OrderKey.  However, Textbox1 (in GroupBox1) does not show any values.  I have determined that GroupBox1 is indeed using a separate BindingContext and position commands do move to new rows independent of the form.  If I comment out setting GroupBox1's BindingContext it behaves as Texbox2, synchronized at the form level.  If I uncomment setting Groupbox2's BindingContext, it behaves as Textbox1, unsynchronized but doesn't display any values in the textbox.

Can anybody see what I'm missing?

Here is the full code:

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1

Dim ds As New DataSet1

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    BindControls()
    GetData()
End Sub

Private Sub BindControls()
    Dim bcG1 As New BindingContext()
    Dim bcG2 As New BindingContext()

    GroupBox1.BindingContext = bcG1
    'GroupBox2.BindingContext = bcG2

    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Orders.OrderKey")    ' groupbox1
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Orders.OrderKey")    ' groupbox2
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", ds, "Orders.OrderKey")    ' form
End Sub

' ** groupbox1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    GroupBox1.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position -= 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(GroupBox1.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox5.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    GroupBox1.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position += 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(GroupBox1.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox5.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    GroupBox2.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position -= 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(GroupBox2.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox6.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub


' ** groupbox2
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    GroupBox2.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position += 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(GroupBox2.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox6.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    Me.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position -= 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(Me.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox4.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

' ** Form
Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Me.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position += 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(Me.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox4.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub GetDataButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetDataButton.Click
    GetData()
End Sub

Public Sub GetData()
    ds.Clear()
    Dim ota As New DataSet1TableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter
    ota.Adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT OrderKey, CustomerFK, OrderDate, DeliveryMethod, Special_Instr, " & _
            "TotalOrderAmount " & _
            "FROM Orders ", ota.Connection)
    ota.Adapter.Fill(ds)
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Tested setting GropuBox2.BindingContext = Me.BindingContext.  This linked the two but TextBox2 no longer showed a value.  Seems that if the GroupBox's DataContext is set, the contained TextBoxes' Text properties don't get bound.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft declined to address the bug report at this time but I did find that I could use BindingSources to accomplish what I was trying to do. Important note:  To set the filter the BindingSource.DataSource property needs to be set to a new DataView. By default it uses the DataTable's default view so setting the filter on one instance of the BindingSource sets it for the other.  The DataSource assignment would be similar to this:

BindingSource1.DataSource = New DataView(DataSource1.DataTable1)

Here is the revised code:

```
Imports System
```

Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class Form1BindingSource

```
Dim ds As New DataSet1
Dim bsForm As BindingSource
Dim bsG1 As BindingSource
Dim bsG2 As BindingSource
Dim BindingSource1 As BindingSource

Private _OcConnectionString As String
Public Property OcConnectionString() As String
    Get
        Return _OcConnectionString
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _OcConnectionString = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    BindControls()
    GetData()
End Sub

Public Sub New(strConnection As String)
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
    OcConnectionString = strConnection
    BindControls()
    GetData()
End Sub

Private Sub BindControls()

    bsForm = New BindingSource
    bsG1 = New BindingSource
    bsG2 = New BindingSource

    bsForm.DataSource = ds
    bsG1.DataSource = ds
    bsG2.DataSource = ds

    bsForm.DataMember = "Orders"
    bsG1.DataMember = "Orders"
    bsG2.DataMember = "Orders"

    'BindingSource1 = New BindingSource(ds, "Orders")
    BindingSource1 = New BindingSource
    BindingSource1.DataSource = ds
    BindingSource1.DataMember = "Orders"
    Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1

    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsG1, "OrderKey")    ' groupbox1
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsG2, "OrderKey")    ' groupbox2
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "OrderKey")    ' form
    TextBox8.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "OrderKey")    ' Groupbox3

End Sub

' ** groupbox1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    bsG1.MovePrevious()
    'GroupBox1.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position -= 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsG1.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox5.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    bsG1.MoveNext()
    'GroupBox1.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position += 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsG1.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox5.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

' ** groupbox2
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    bsG2.MovePrevious()
    'GroupBox2.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position -= 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsG2.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox6.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    bsG2.MoveNext()
    'GroupBox2.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position += 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsG2.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox6.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

'** form level
Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    bsForm.MovePrevious()
    'Me.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position -= 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsForm.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox4.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    bsForm.MoveNext()
    'Me.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position += 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsForm.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox4.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

'** Groupbox3
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    bsForm.MovePrevious()
    'GroupBox3.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position -= 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsForm.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox8.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    bsForm.MoveNext()
    'GroupBox3.BindingContext(ds, "Orders").Position += 1
    Dim drv As DataRowView = CType(bsForm.Current, DataRowView)
    TextBox8.Text = drv("OrderKey")
End Sub

Private Sub GetDataButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GetDataButton.Click
    GetData()
End Sub

Public Sub GetData()
    Try
        Dim ota As New DataSet1TableAdapters.OrdersTableAdapter
        If OcConnectionString IsNot Nothing Then
            ota.Connection.ConnectionString = OcConnectionString
        End If
        ds.Clear()
        ota.Adapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT OrderKey, CustomerFK, OrderDate, DeliveryMethod, Special_Instr, " & _
                "TotalOrderAmount " & _
                "FROM Orders ", ota.Connection)
        ota.Adapter.Fill(ds)
    Catch exp As Exception
        MsgBox(exp.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

End Class

Carl